# how to edit and update xml files in a directory in python

Tags: python-2.7

there are many file in a folder named "ini" an i have to search a file with attribute name
and edit its value, i've tried this code:-

```
import os, glob
from lxml import etree

for filename in glob.glob("./ini/*.xml"):

    xmlData = etree.parse(filename)

    for msg in xmlData.findall("//Value"):
        name = msg.attrib["name"]
        init = msg.attrib["initValue"]
        if name == "attribute name" :
            msg.set("initValue", "0")
            print msg.get('name'), msg.get('initValue')
            print msg.attrib
            print name, init
            print filename
```

the value is updated only in "msg" not in original file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have reached a point where you have *read*, *parsed* and *modified* the xml file. The last step is missing which is to *save* the file since the modified version only exists in the memory of your running process.

```
with open("outfile.xml", "w") as f:
    f.write(etree.tostring(xmlData))
```

This will write the modified xml to *outfile.xml* in a pretty printed (indented) format. You will be able to overwrite the original file by replacing *"outfile.xml"* with the variable containing your original filename.